# Sharing mysql databases with windows

Tags: 16.04, mount, mysql, windows-10

I develop mostly on Ubuntu 16.04 but at times I'm forced to go to Windows 10 to for example use Photoshop or maybe connect to a wireless display when doing a demo where there's no HDMI cable.

I would like to be able to have a common mysql database data folder to be able to access databases seamlessy (hopefully) accross both operating systems.

I tried mounting the data folder onto my ntfs drive but one challenge I'm facing with on my Ubuntu implementation is that I have to manually "initialise" (for lack of a better word) the NTFS drive by browsing the media through the Files application to be able to start accessing files in applications such as Atom or even on the CLI.

Anyone kind enough to write one last updated tutorial?

Comment: The only way that i can see, is running mysql on docker on both OSs with a shared data volume on a ntfs partition that both linux and windows can mount properly.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking but it appears you're looking for a way to mount an NTFS file system during boot and before MySQL starts. Is that correct? In that case your question would be a duplicate of [How to automount NTFS partitions?](/q/46588/175814)

Answer (score 1):

### Sharing mysql Databases with Windows

You don't browse the media to access the database.  You use an **SQL** client to access the database.  You provide the access information to the **SQL** client.

Windows has a GUI under **Adminstrative Tools** to add a **Data Source** which you configure for your **[SQL/MSQL client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows.html)**.

While the details are provided in the link, you can get support for configuring the client from your friendly Microsoft Support channel.

For the Ubuntu side use these steps:
[Using MS Access to import from mysql](https://askubuntu.com/a/876427/29012)

Configure the Mysql with these details:

- Database Name
- Username
- Password

Enter that information along with the hostname or IP address of your database and use the Microsoft client to connect to it.

### Automatically mounting your Windows NTFS folder

You can automatically mount your **NTFS** driver or partition, but adding an entry to your `/etc/fstab` file.

Add this endry.  Replace the "UUID" number of the UUID with the UUID of your NTFS partition.

```
UUID="3874F30874F2C820" /mnt2/windowsdrive    ntfs  defaults  0  0
```

The `/mnt2/windowsdrive` is a mounting point.  You can use any location on your hard drive for this point.  To create the location, use this command:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt2/windowsdrive
```

Run this command to find the **UUID** of this drive for your `etc/fstab` entry.

```
$ sudo blkid
```

Replace the `/mnt2/windowsdrive` and `UUID="60292932-ae7d-4676-8f0f-7c319cb66fee"` entries with the information from your system.

Now you can manually mount it (or test the configuration) with this command:

```
$ sudo mount /mnt2/windowsdrive
```

You should now be able to navigate to that mounted point.  When you reboot the point will automatically be mounted.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't articulate enough. The reason why I browse the media is so that I can be able to access any document or file from my application say code files on Atom. Its more like initialising the drive

Comment: @MasindeMuliro  Please look at the amended information in the answer on automatically mounting your **NTFS** partition.  Please let me know if  this clears up your problem, of if you still have issues with the sharing.